# how to know the memory usage of machine by using ip address,protocol and pro

Tags: java, sockets, memory

suppose, we having host api and api having ip address,port and protocol.
How to know the memory usage ,cpu usage ,disk usage of api

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by exposing a `/health` endpoint in your api. This api would return the memory usage, cpu usage, disk usage in a machine readable format such as JSON.

You could look at already existing packages such as prometheus or the ELK stack. Both have client libraries for java [prometheus client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java) en [ELK stack](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.2/getting-started-with-logstash.html).

Comment: can u please privide code for healthcheck for particular api

Comment: You could try using the supplied prometheus client @PrinceGupta